# SCALA: monix Obeservable method

Tags: scala

I am trying to use Monix Observable to control the big memory of file into smaller chunks of bytes so that it won't use up too many RAM to load the file's bytes.

However, when I using Observable.frominputStreram, it doesn't provide the `Array[Byte]` that fills into `update()` function from `MessageDigest`.

Any suggestions on my codes?

```scala
def SHA256_5(file: File)= {
      val sha256 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
      val in: Observable[Array[Byte]] = {
        Observable.fromInputStream(Task(new FileInputStream(file)))
      }
      in.map(byteArray=>sha256.update(byteArray)).completed
      sha256.digest().map("%02x".format(_)).mkString

    }
```

```
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val path = "C:\\Users\\ME\\IdeaProjects\\HELLO\\src\\main\\scala\\TRY.scala"
    println(SHA256_5(new File(path)))

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
in.map(byteArray=>sha256.update(byteArray)).completed
```

returns `Task` - it means that you have to execute that `Task` and *when it finishes* you will be able to call

```
sha256.digest().map("%02x".format(_)).mkString
```

because Task is used for lazily building asynchronous operation.

Try this instead:

```
def calcuateSHA(file: File) = for {
  sha256 <- Task(MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256"))
  in = Observable.fromInputStream(Task(new FileInputStream(file)))
  _ <- in.map(byteArray=>sha256.update(byteArray)).completed
} yield sha256.digest().map("%02x".format(_)).mkString

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val path = "C:\\Users\\ME\\IdeaProjects\\HELLO\\src\\main\\scala\\TRY.scala"

  import monix.execution.Implicits.global
  Await.result(calcuateSHA(new File(path)).runToFuture, Duration.Inf)
}
```

for starters, or if you want to do it using build in Monix `TaskApp` instead of hacks for running asynchronous computation in a synchronous `main`:

```
object Test extends TaskApp {

  def calcuateSHA(file: File) = for {
    sha256 <- Task(MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256"))
    in = Observable.fromInputStream(Task(new FileInputStream(file)))
    _ <- in.map(byteArray=>sha256.update(byteArray)).completed
  } yield sha256.digest().map("%02x".format(_)).mkString

  def run(args: List[String]) = {
    val path = "C:\\Users\\ME\\IdeaProjects\\HELLO\\src\\main\\scala\\TRY.scala"
    for {
      sha <- calcuateSHA(new File(path)
      _ = println(sha)
    } yield ExitCode.Success
  }
}
```

Comment: It works fine for me! However, is that possible that I use `runAsync` here, instead of `Await` ? Or any examples of how to execute `Task` here? Thanks!

Comment: If you run `runAsync` , Task will be sent to thread pool. Which by default (inless you create your own) is a daemon thread pool meaning that if all non-daemon thread finished, JVM can be closed. `main` thread is non-daemon, but `Implicits.global` is, so after you trigger `Task` JVM will close immediately before you receive the result. The solution is to either create your own non-daemon thread pool (but then you have to close it manually, or JVM will "hang") or `Await`. Or use `TaskApp` which solved that issue already.